# Upgrading to php 5.5 error Centos 7 Apache 2.4

Tags: php, apache, centos

So I'm trying to upgrade php versions. I have removed all of the 5.4 stuff and dependencies.

I am following this link https://webtatic.com/packages/php55/

I perform the first two steps:

```
rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm
```

Then this:

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum install php55w php55w-opcache
```

And it does some stuff and then I get these errors:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php55w-common-5.5.25-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
       Requires: libgmp.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: php55w-5.5.25-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
       Requires: httpd-mmn = 20051115
       Installed: httpd-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.x86_64 (@base)
           httpd-mmn = 20120211
           httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664
           httpd-mmn = 20120211-x86-64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Found out that mmn means module magic number. And cant seem to find libgmp.so.3 for centos, so I am about to break my computer.

Thanks

Comment: did you try `Remi's` repo for PHP? https://www.mojowill.com/geek/howto-install-php-5-4-5-5-or-5-6-on-centos-6-and-centos-7/

Comment: libgmp.so is from openssl rpm on CentOS 5.5. `rpm -qf /usr/lib/openssl/engines/libgmp.so` openssl-0.9.8e-12.el5_4.6. Do you have openssl installed?

Comment: @Panama Jack thank you so much. I followed that step for step and it worked. What a life saver

Answer (score 3):

I'd also encountered this problem while installing php70w. And after I cleaned the yum's cache, it disapeared:

```
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum install -y php70w
```

Comment: `yum clean all` did the trick for me. I encountered this problem because I added a CentOS6 repot to a CentOS7 install. Until deleting the repo files in `/etc/yum.repos/` and adding the right repo, I still got errors. - Until I cleaned up the yum caches. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd also encountered this problem. And after I cleaned the `yum`'s cache, it disapeared:

```
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum install -y php55w
```

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 1):

the following worked for me to upgrade PHP from 5.4.16 to 5.5.38 (CentOS 7):

```
yum install -y http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-10.noarch.rpm http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm

yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55 update -y php*
```

To upgrade to 5.6.31 use instead:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php56 update -y php*
```

The same works for 7.x (remi-php7x)

Comment: Don't forget that PHP 5.5 is EOL ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using **EPEL7** with **CentOS 7**. To fix:

```
 #rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm 

 #yum remove epel-release  

 #yum install epel-release
```